# How to remove the launcher icon in android 10(Q)

Tags: android, visibility, android-10.0, appicon

Before API 29, we can remove the launcher icon in the device by removing

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

in the manifest file.

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps#getActivityList(java.lang.String,%20android.os.UserHandle))

> As of Android Q, at least one of the app's activities or synthesized activities appears in the returned list unless the app satisfies at least one of the following conditions:

- > The app is a system app.
- > The app doesn't request any permissions.
- > The app doesn't have a launcher activity that is enabled by default. A
  >   launcher activity has an intent containing the ACTION_MAIN action and
  >   the CATEGORY_LAUNCHER category.
- > Additionally, the system hides
  >   synthesized activities for some or all apps in the following
  >   enterprise-related cases:
  >
  > If the device is a fully managed device, no synthesized activities for
  >   any app appear in the returned list. If the current user has a work
  >   profile, no synthesized activities for the user's work apps appear in
  >   the returned list.

The third condition states as the same as not to have a launcher activity that is enabled.

How to achieve this in android 10?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Ranjan No did not get any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I believe the third condition is wrong or outdated.

The behavior on Google's current emulator image of Android 10 (Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image 29_r09) differs from the documentation:

[getActivityList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps#getActivityList(java.lang.String,%20android.os.UserHandle)) always returns at least one activity, except if the app satisfies at least one:

- system app
- <application> tag is completely empty i.e. no activities, services, ... declared
- no permissions declared

This behavior corresponds to the [release notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20190829024136/https://developer.android.com/preview/release-notes#launcher-icon-visibility-beta2) from Android Q Beta:

> Launcher icon visibility
>
> In Android Q Beta 2, packages that don't declare any permissions in their respective
>   manifest files are hidden from the All apps tray, as are the following types of apps:
>
> - System apps
> - Apps that don't contain any components inside their respective manifest's <application> tag

Comment: this should have been a comment not an answer